How to get file name from URLSession.shared.data get request
I am getting CSV file from the server with URLSession.shared.data get request:
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.timeoutInterval = 10
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = httpHeaders
let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)

Receive file data as Swift Data, I am also need file name or somehow receive details about file name. I see file name in response:
{ Status Code: 200, Headers {
"Content-Disposition" =     (
    "attachment; filename=\"fileName.csv\""
);

but how I can get this?

Use URLResponse.suggestedFileName.
let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
print(response.suggestefFileName)

From the documentation,

Accessing this property attempts to generate a filename using the following information, in order:

A filename specified using the content disposition header.
The last path component of the URL.
The host of the URL.


Number 1 is exactly what you are trying to get. If there is a Content-Disposition header, that is what will be used.

include Foundation



function fetchDocument(src: URL, httpHeaders: [String: String]) async throws -> (Data, String) {

mutable request = URLRequest(url: src)

request. httpMethod = "GET"

request. timeoutTick = 10

request. allHTTPHeaderFields = httpHeaders



let (info, response) = try await URLSession. shared. data(for: request)



Ensure let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,

let contentDisposition = httpResponse. allHeaderFields["Content-Disposition"] as? String else {

throw URLError(.badServerResponse)

}



let dataName = extractDataName(from: contentDisposition) ?? "defaultDataName. csv"

return (info, dataName)

}



private function extractDataName(from contentDisposition: String) -> String? {

let template = "filename=\"([^\"]+)\""

let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(template: template)

let nsString = contentDisposition as NSString

let outputs = regex?.matches(in: contentDisposition, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: nsString. length))



return outputs?.first. map { nsString. substring(with: $0. range(at: 1)) }

}



// Usage sample

Task {

do {

let src = URL(string: "https://sample. com/route/to/document. csv")!

let headers = ["Authorization": "Bearer token"]

let (data, dataName) = try await fetchDocument(from: src, httpHeaders: headers)

print("Data Name: \(dataName)")

// Process the data as required

} catch {

print("Error fetching document: \(error)")

}

}

Clarification:

fetchFile: Executes the GET solicitation and segregates the a Content-Disposition header.
extractFileName: Leverages regular expressions to analyze and deliver the file name.
Application: Exemplifies the modus operandi of invoking the fetchFile function and dealing with the outcome.


Your code is a mess. No indentation. Way, waaaay too many blank lines. Lots of syntax errors and invalid code.

It's not valid Swift. "include"? "function"? "timeoutTicks"? It's more like badly formatted pseudocode.
